# Getting values from a multiple constructor

Tags: c#, class, constructor

Here is the sample code:

```
class Class1
{
    string a;

    public Class1(string over) : base()
    {
       this.a = over;
       Console.WriteLine(a);
    }

    public Class1(bool check)
    {
       if(check)
         Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 myClass1 = new Class1("test");
        Class1 myClass2 = new Class1(true);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

What I want to happen is to get the value of **string a** from the 1nd Constructor `Class1(string)` and display it to Constructor `Class1(bool)`. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean display it to `Class1(bool)`

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(a);` because its just giving me blank result

Comment: Why would you want to do that? the two objects **should be independent and separate** - why should the `new Class1(true)` know about the existence of the `"test"` string? There are some fundamental problems in the question here, that mean that a different design is wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `string a`static. That way, all instances of Class1 reference the same string.

Comment: It answers the OPs question, but IMO this just papers over some cracks - it makes *no sense* to me that this is a sane thing to do - what if I want multiple `Class` objects with different strings? what about threading? security (of strings that have no business being somewhere else)? This isn't critique of the *answer* - more the fault of the question for not making it clear what and why...

Answer (score 2):

You have two different instances of Class1: myClass1 and MyClass2
If 'a' needs to be shared across instances, then you can make it static.

That way, setting 'a' in any instance of Class1 will apply to all instances.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but i dont think you should be doing that.

```
class Class1 {     

    static string a;  

    public Class1(string over) : base() {        
        a = over;        
        Console.WriteLine(a);     
    }      
    public Class1(bool check)     {        
        if(check)          
            Console.WriteLine(a);     
        } 
    }  

    class Program {     
        static void Main(string[] args)     {         
            Class1 myClass1 = new Class1("test");         
            Class1 myClass2 = new Class1(true);         
            Console.ReadLine();     
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your code won't compile, because you forgot the curly brace after `if(check)`. Should be  `if(check){`. And I don't think you should try to call Main from a nested class!!

Answer (score 0):

Pass myClass1 to myClass2 in a method call (or in the constructor)

It is hard to tell what to do because Class1, a, over, check. They don't make sense to me.